# Combinatorial isomorphisms of 2-connected plane graphs are topological

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

In Diestel Theorem 4.3.1 (ii) it says "Every combinatorial isomorphism between two 2-connected plane graphs is topological."

I don't understand, where in the proof do we use the fact that the graphs are 2-connected?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: In the use of Proposition 4.2.6